# CellForItemAtIndexPath is not responding to UICollectionVieLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am working on `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and my target of the applications is to re size image's  in  layouts between small size and  big size  and put UILable in Big size image view layout and remove in small size layout using a button.

I can successfully re-size the image layouts, but I have 1 problem and 2 questions in this scenario.

Problem 1:

`CellForItemAtIndexPath` is not called every time,  i tried using `reloadData` but it say
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in a empty snapshot. ensure your view has been
rendered at least once before snapshotting. How to get ride of this problem and call this method.

Question 1:

How can  i display UILabel in large view and remove in small view

Question 2:

If i am in 4th row of Large image layout and go to small view image layout and come back to large view layout. How can i display the same 4th row image in Large view layout, instead of showing again refreshed screen.

Please find my code for your reference below:

```
{//View Controller

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController  : UICollectionViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
-(void)animationDidChange:(id)sender;
@end


#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
#import "SingleView.h"
#import "GridView.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SingleView *largeLayout;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GridView *smallLayout;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;
@property(nonatomic, strong)UIButton * button;


@end

static NSString *ItemIdentifier = @"ItemIdentifier";

@implementation ViewController

-(void)loadView
{


    self.smallLayout = [[GridView alloc] init];
    self.largeLayout = [[SingleView alloc] init];

    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:self.largeLayout];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemIdentifier];

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.collectionView.bounces = YES;
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    self.collectionView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=YES;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 18, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
    toolbar.barTintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    //Added Label to toolbar for title
    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 23)];
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label2.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label2.text = @"Title";
    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    UIBarButtonItem *toolBarTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label2];
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil    action:nil];
    //Added button to the toolbar
   _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [_button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(animationDidChange:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 210.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    UIBarButtonItem *toolBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_button];
    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: toolBarTitle,spacer,toolBarButton, nil];
    [toolbar setItems:items];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = toolbar;

  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - User Interface Methods

-(void)animationDidChange:(id)sender
{
    CollectionViewCell * cell= [[CollectionViewCell alloc]init];
    if (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout == self.smallLayout)
    {
[_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.largeLayout invalidateLayout];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.largeLayout animated:YES];

    }
    else if(self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout == self.largeLayout)
    {
[_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.smallLayout invalidateLayout];

        [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.smallLayout animated:YES];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionView DataSource & Delegate methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 11;
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"groupA_%ld.jpg", indexPath.row ]]];

        return cell;



}


@end


//COllectionViewCell

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel * dateString;
@property(nonatomic, strong)UILabel* nameString;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString* layout;
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image;
-(void)setLabel;
-(void)removeLabel;
@end


#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
@interface  CollectionViewCell()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;


@end
@implementation CollectionViewCell
@synthesize dateString,nameString,layout;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

    if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) return nil;

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame)), 0, 0)];

    self.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
     self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    if ([self.layout isEqualToString: @"small"]) {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
    }
    self.dateString =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 270, 350, 20)];
   self.nameString =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 290, 350, 20)];


    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dateString];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.nameString];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return self;
}



-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{

    self.imageView.image = image;
}

-(void)setLabel{

self.dateString.text =@"Hello";

}
-(void)removeLabel{
    [self.dateString removeFromSuperview];
}

@end


//CollectionView layout Large

@interface SingleView : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end

#import "SingleView.h"

@implementation SingleView
-(id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(350, 300);
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0);
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0f;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0f;


    return self;
}
@end

//CollectionViewLayout Small


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GridView : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end


#import "GridView.h"

@implementation GridView
-(id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(130, 130);
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 40, 10, 40);
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0f;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0f;
    return self;
}

@end

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have direct answer for your problem. I had something similar when I resized my view on device rotation and it went away by moving the methods into 
´viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        [self landscapeUISetup];

    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [self portraitUISetup];
        NSLog(@"portrait");

    }

}
```

For the question 1, I would suggest trying simple hiding of the label when you load the small view. 
So something like

```
self.label.hidden = YES;
```

And when you change back to large

```
self.label.hidden = NO;
```

For question 2:
You need to save the index of the visible cell and then call the scrolling method

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
```

Comment: What size do you think creates a problem width or height?

Comment: I think the problem is that the view is changed in the wrong place. Just try to make your changes inside `viewDidLayoutSubview` and see if the error goes away. The error message could also be a bug in iOS 8. You can see many posts if you search with that message.